# Using two 12V batteries, while simultaneously charging?

Tags: power-supply

I would like to deepen and clarify the question.

Specifically, I'm planning on using an electric wheelchair to transport equipment for me. Two, 12V 75A batteries are my power source. The wheelchair has two 24V/300W motors.

I'd like to throw a little Honda generator on top, with a battery charger, with two 12V 10A outputs. I'm not looking for "endless" power. Simply greater range, and a little loving care for my batteries.

The charger I've found is 220V/3A. My Generator output is 220V/1000W.

What are my chances of this working?

Answer (score 2):

I expect that the two outputs of the charger really come from the same power source, so share a common ground - if that is the case, your plan won't work, as the common ground connection will short the "bottom" battery.

However, if the charger outputs are isolated, or you use two independent chargers, it would work (but be sure that the DC outputs of the chargers are not connected to the AC ground in any way).

Answer (score 0):

Very little, as I'm assuming the 12V outputs are not isolated from each other.  Connecting them in series will likely short the supply, making it impossible to charge on the fly.